# Entitymanager query in 2 different tables with inner join

Tags: java, jpa

my current code:

```
TypedQuery<Account> tp = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Account a INNER JOIN User u ON u.account_id = a.id WHERE a.email = :email AND a.pwd = :pwd AND a.role = 'admin'", Account.class);
                tp.setParameter("email", this.username);
                tp.setParameter("pwd", this.password);
                Account result = tp.getSingleResult();
```

but ill get an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

what i need is to display a column in the user table.

something like `String name = Account.getName();` but the Account entity doesnt have a getName() only the User entity has.

*update

this is the error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT a FROM Account a INNER JOIN User u ON u.account_id = a.id WHERE a.email = :email AND a.pwd = :pwd AND a.role = 'admin']. Internal Exception: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.EarlyExitException

Comment: Can you post your stack trace...

Comment: Are these actually two questions? For a start, where does the IllegalArgumentException occur?

Comment: the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException occurs on the createQuery. maybe the query is incorrect. I updated the question for the error

Comment: Try: SELECT a FROM Account a INNER JOIN a.user u ON u.account_id = a.id WHERE a.email = :email AND a.pwd = :pwd AND a.role = 'admin'

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT a FROM Account a INNER JOIN a.user u ON u.account_id = a.id WHERE a.email = :email AND a.pwd = :pwd AND a.role = 'admin'], line 1, column 44: unexpected token [ON]. Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(80@[()* loopback of 477:9: (node= join )*])

tried and that was the error, the User is actually a different table

Comment: @galao You can ignore the ON condition as its implicit. My mistake.

Comment: As a side note, you can use @ with username to reply to a specific user. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911616/join-two-un-related-tables-using-jpa-entitymanager) article explains you have to JOIN like that : you specifiy the table names separated by a coma, and you move the `ON` condition in the `WHERE`.

```
TypedQuery<Account> tp = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Account a, User u   WHERE u.account_id = a.id AND a.email = :email AND a.pwd = :pwd AND a.role = 'admin'", Account.class);
            tp.setParameter("email", this.username);
            tp.setParameter("pwd", this.password);
            Account result = tp.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`result.getUser().getName();`

This, though, is under the assumption, that your Account class has a relationship with the User class.

The assumption of this being **Hibernate/JPA** relationship comes from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848637/extracting-the-values-inside-an-object) and the use **HQL** in your code above.

Comment: yes, the account has a relationship on user class. but i think the query is wrong.